# WordPress woocommerce plugin changing theme layout

Tags: jquery, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, css-selectors

I am developing a woocommerce related theme and issue I am facing is that when ever I go to shop page or any page it changes my layout. It removes my `.container` class and convert that class to `#container` id and so my 1170px layout is not showing up and all my data is 100%.

I am new to woocommerce kindly guide me how to fix this?

My container class is working fine on all other pages instead woocommerce.

Comment: It is possible that the template is not being applied. Can you share relevant code?

Comment: I have no code at all ... I just created a shop page in backend and assigned that page to show products from woocommerce settings. In that page a container class is written that takes my layout inside 1170px ... but woocommerce not showing up that code at all ... :(

Comment: There's more robust solution than adding jQuery at the end -- edit `woocommerce/templates/global/wrapper-start.php` to include your container class, just fixed this problem in a consulting project I'm working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not located on woocommerce templates like suggest your answer, but in the `woocommerce.php` file located in your active theme folder.

There you will need add in the `id="container"` html tag all occurrences, a `class="container"`. For example:

```
<div id="container">
```

Will need to be replace by:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
```

Or by:

```
<div class="container">
```

This will solve your issue.

Another solution without editing this `woocommerce.php` file is adding for example a jQuery script like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "body.woocommerce-page #container" ).addClass( "container" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got it by my self. That was due to just because I was showing posts from WooCommerce Plugin templates and that's default behavior of the WooCommerce. I just copied `archive-product.php` page to my theme directory and wrapped all code inside my all content  and it worked like a charm :)
Hope, that will solve problems of any new comer like me ...